# EXCEL 2007: Compare each column A cell in workbook1 to see if it exists in the strings of of column A in workbooks 2-4

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I will say I have no idea where to begin, but am not afraid to get into VBA if needed (never done it, but can code in other languages).

My company possesses a master list of 800 numbers. I have 4 global regions. I the 4 global workbooks column A represents the last 4 of the 800 numbers from the master list. I need to check that every "last 4" is checked against the master list and report those which are not represented.

So it needs to For Each regional workbook column A and return true if it exists in Master workbook column A. Else, I need it to generate a list of the rows which are not matched against the master list.

Where can I learn such skills?

EDIT Added:

[masterbook example](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6nD6z7RLy_Kd2pkTU12ODl6MjQ)

[region1 exmaple](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6nD6z7RLy_KRlFaRnBkUTV1WmM)

[region2 example](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6nD6z7RLy_KT2VlaXVaY21fcHc)

Comment: i'm not quite understanding what you need. can you please explain it better?  "the 4 global workbooks column A represents the last 4 of the 800 numbers from the master list." what is this "last 4"? makes no sense.

Comment: @cullan The master list contains the entire 800.111.1234 numbers. The regional sheets only contain the last 4 (XXX.XXX.1234). So I need to verify that every last 4 on the regional sheets are present on the master list.

Comment: Put here workbook example and desired result\sheet screenshot

Comment: @bzimor   examples added, thank you

Comment: @Adam, let me know if the below works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your master workbook's location is the same with your region workbook and it isn't changed, just use this formula into cell B2 and press **CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER** then fill down:

```
=IF(OR(TEXT(A2,0)=RIGHT('masterlist example.xlsx'!$A$2:$A$1000,4)),"YES","NO")
```

Comment: This works well enough to get done what I needed. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

VBA Solution: What i'm doing here is saving all the master numbers in an array. Then I am looping through each region worksheet, and I am checking each number within the region to see if any element's last 4 in the master array is equal to that region's number and if it is, then I make the element in that array equal to blank. At the end, I go through the array to find any numbers that are not blank (ie. these are the numbers that aren't present in any of the regions) and then i message output them.

```
Sub findMissingNumbers()
    Dim numbers() As String
    With Worksheets("Master")
        For i = 2 To .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown)).Count
            ReDim Preserve numbers(i)
            numbers(i - 2) = .Cells(i, 1).Value
        Next i
    End With

    For Each ws In Worksheets
        With ws
            If (Not ws.Name = "Master") Then
                For Each cell In .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(2, 1).End(xlDown))
                    For i = 0 To UBound(numbers) - 1
                        last4master = Right(numbers(i), 4)
                        If (last4master = CStr(cell.Value)) Then
                            numbers(i) = ""
                        End If
                    Next i
                Next cell
            End If
        End With
    Next ws

    missingNumbers = ""
    For Each num In numbers
        If (Not num = "") Then
            missingNumbers = missingNumbers & num & vbNewLine
        End If
    Next num

    MsgBox missingNumbers
End Sub
```

Comment: This is a fantastic solution and an even better look into VBA for me to learn from, for thank I thank you greatly.